# Count the number of words ends with specific character using Bash

Tags: bash, shell, grep, curl

Heys guys I wanted to count the number of words that end with 's' from this URL,

https://matt.might.net/articles/what-cs-majors-should-know/

Here's what I did

```
curl https://matt.might.net/articles/what-cs-majors-should-know/ | \
grep s$
```

I couldn't find a way to filter out the words that end with 's' and count them

Comment: How do you define a *word*. Is `<canvas>` a word ending in `>`? Do you want to find the words in the HTML source, or in some rendition of the HTML into text? If the latter, how should that rendition be done, etc.

Comment: So like after curling the URL I get the HTML of a text file and I want to count the total number the words  that end with 's'.

Answer (score 3):

```
elinks -no-numbering -no-references -dump https://matt.might.net/articles/what-cs-majors-should-know/ |
  grep -Po '\w+s\b' |
  wc -l
```

(with GNU `grep` or compatible)

Gives me: `595`

`elinks` retrieves the HTML and converts it to text in its own way. Some alternatives are `w3m -dump` or `lynx -nolist`.

Then we look for the sequences of one or more word characters in there (word characters being alnums or underscores) followed by a `s` provided it's not followed by a word character, and count then with `wc -l`.

In essence, the definition of a word there is a sequence of 2 or more alnum or underscore characters and we look for the ones ending in `s` (add a `-i` option to `grep` to also look for those ending in `S`). That means the `s` in `it's` for instance is not counted. If you want wanted to consider single-letter words, you could replace `+` with `*` above. Or just do `grep -Po 's\b'` but then you wouldn't be able to see the list of words when omitting the `| wc -l`.

Another approach would be to extract the words first and find the ones ending in `s`:

```
grep -Eo '\w+' | grep -c 's$'
```

In any case, that's quite a crude definition of *word* that only works properly for simple English text. When applied to text in other languages, you could run into problems. For instance, it would find a match inside the `abrogowałybyście` Polish word (picked at random in a word list) if that `ś` was encoded in its decomposed `s`U+0301 form (where U+0301 is the combining acute accent) as that `s` would be seen as not being followed by a word character.

You may also want to consider what to do about the `S` in `USA` or `U.S.A.`.